# Unable to run react-native on android device

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I have a fresh install of Sierra, Xcode 8.1, and then used Homebrew to install node, watchman, react-native-cli etc.. created a new react native app and it runs fine with "react-native run-ios".

So I installed Android Studio and then started to follow

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html

If I start an emulator "react-native run-android" installs fine and runs, but I cannot get it to run on a device.

The first device in the list is my Samsung Duo

```
$adb devices 
List of devices attached
f75807c3    device
```

lsusb gives me the connected device

```
$lsusb
Bus 020 Device 005: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd. Android  Serial: f75807c3
```

Then I need to input this into my udev rules in order to get up and running:

```
echo SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-usb.rules
```

Making sure that I replace 22b8 with 04e8. Returned with no errors.

Now when I check that my device is properly connecting to ADB, the Android Debug Bridge, by using adb devices I get the same list, not a changed list as shown in the online example.

```
$adb devices
List of my devices attached
f75807c3    device
```

same as before (has linking failed here??)

On Running on Device webpage

```
List of devices attached at start of example
emulator-5554 offline   # Google emulator
14ed2fcc device         # Physical device

List of devices attached at end of page of example
TA9300GLMK    device
```

I get the same device both times, just
    f75807c3    device

and when I "react-native run-android" I get this error

> :app:installDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
>
>   > Failed to install on any devices.

What do I need to do to run this on a real device?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find the generated apk under $YOUR_PATH/android/build/outputs/apk/, use `adb install $PATH_TO_THE_APK` to install on your devices, usually adb will print much more error info about the installation.

Answer (score -1):

check to make sure you are connected properly to your machines ip address
devsettings ==> debug server host & port for device --> enter ip address and port e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081

Comment: Where this set must be made?

Comment: Once the redcolor screen is shown then shake the device and open the dev settings

Comment: Once the redcolor screen is shown then shake the device and open the dev settings